# css :not with wildcard *

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to do something similar to below without filling my document with show and hide classes:

```
 body.vnu-hours-sel *:not(#results-content) {
    visibility:hidden;

  }
```

basically everything within **.vnu-hours-sel** apart from a div with the id results-content needs to be hidden (print style sheet!)

Comment: you will need at least 2 styles: one to hide and one to show. I don't think you can do this using one statement

Comment: cheers @TemaniAfif - thought as much - was just hoping for some genius workaround as 2 classes is a bit of a pain in this scenario.  cheers

Comment: you don't need classes, simply 2 rules: https://jsfiddle.net/1e3785t0/ (more accurate: https://jsfiddle.net/20b4a6fs/)

Comment: The asterisk (`*`) is redundant. Just FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

Clearly this works **if**  your target is a direct child of the parent.

```css
.vnu-hours-sel *:not(#results-content) {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="vnu-hours-sel">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="results-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise you will need to reset the visibility of the target to override the hidden value of it's ancestor.

```css
.vnu-hours-sel *:not(#results-content) {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.vnu-hours-sel #results-content {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="vnu-hours-sel">
  <div>
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="results-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need this *just* for a print style use a media query

```
@media print {
  /* code here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would work even without the *

```css
body :not(#test) {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Edorka/pen/VwwRGmx